# RubyOnbRails - Render mail to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a RubyOnRails 3.2.x application that sends out mails using Actionmailer.

The code goes something like this:

```
class Mymailer < ActionMailer::Base

    def sendout
        mail(:to->"someone@somewhere.com", :from ...........
    end

end
```

Instead of sending out that email, I want it to be rendered to a string which I then plan to process differently

PS: In my specific case I want to pass that string to a Node.JS server who will do the actual sending of the mail, I am using RubyOnRails to handle the multi language support and number formatting (yes I have multiple templates for the different languages that I support).

Comment: Out of interest, why is Rails not sufficient for sending the email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Ruby won't be doing the email sending, there's no need to use the `Mailer`.

Ideally you could generate a [JSON](http://www.json.org) string representation of the email like:

```
# at the top of the file
require 'json'

# then in your method
json_string = { 
  :to => "email@example.com",
  :from =>"sender@example.com",
  :body => "this is the body"
}.to_json
```

Then post this string to your node.js server from (for example) your controller or whatever is currently calling your mailer.

However, since you want to render the email using templates which pull in DB fields and use the i18n functionality of Rails, you could use the `Mailer` but render the result to a string like follows:

```
mail(to: "mail@example.com") do |format|
  format.html do
    string = render_to_string("your_template")

    call_node_js(string)
  end
end
```

Comment: that works for a simple text mail, I have rather "large" emails with lots of database field values in it. All in all I am currently supporting 4 languages, and more to come, hence my wish to reuse the I18n support of Rails.

Comment: can't you render it to HTML and then use the escaped HTML string as a value in your JSON?

Comment: Awesome, did the change and works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is getting the **whole** mail representation, including headers, then you might want to browse the source code to see what happens behind the curtain.

A good starting point is the `ActionMailer::Base` method `#mail` (Rails 4):
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail

Anyway, if the sending is handled by Node.js, you don't need to do it. Just build a JSON object like Olly suggested and pass it through.